# SQL Query to capture data every 5 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Query which captures process memory data for the server. I am trying to chart the results of the query in Power BI. Since there is no date column in sys.dm_os_process_memory system view, i am finding it hard to chart the data over a period of time. Below is the SQL Query:

```
    SELECT   
snapshot_time=sysdatetime()   ,
@@servername AS sql_instance ,
[physical_memory_in_use_kb]
      ,[large_page_allocations_kb]
      ,[locked_page_allocations_kb]
      ,[total_virtual_address_space_kb]
      ,[virtual_address_space_reserved_kb]
      ,[virtual_address_space_committed_kb]
      ,[virtual_address_space_available_kb]
      ,[page_fault_count]
      ,[memory_utilization_percentage]
      ,[available_commit_limit_kb]
      ,[process_physical_memory_low]
      ,[process_virtual_memory_low]
  FROM [sys].[dm_os_process_memory]
```

This is the screen shot of the query results:
[image]

How can i capture the data for every 5 minutes.

Comment: *"How can i capture the data for every 5 minutes"* By running the query every 5 minutes and storing that information *somewhere*.

Comment: Use the SQL Agent to do so

Comment: @Larnu , could you elaborate a bit more and guide me to a reference

Comment: @SQLpro, how can i do that , is there some example I can refer to